# Identify bad creds passed to AD

Tags: active-directory

Does Active Directory log, transmit, or otherwise identify the password (either the hash or plain text) that was used when an account fails to authenticate due to bad creds ?

I'm working on a SIEM query/use case and would love to be able to identify at least the hash of the bad password that was passed to AD.

It most likely doesn't since I have searched everywhere and haven't found an answer but I figured I would ask you fine folks.

Comment: Consdering how bad that would be from a security standpoint, it's very unlikely.

Comment: I figured as much but if it already existed I wouldn't be opposed to leveraging it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.

And if it did, attackers would find a way to leverage that information for evil.

For example, I could easily imagine using that data of users' previous password patterns to guess what their future passwords would look like.